# InterruptedException and Intellij check: var can't be null

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea

Intellij says that process can't be null. If I change exception to other then there is no warnings. Why is that so?

```
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("my command");
        int execResult = process.waitFor();
        if (execResult != 0){
            ...
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        if (process != null && process.isAlive()) process.destroy();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
```

Comment: The `InterruptedException` could be thrown by `#waitFor`, but the line before it will never throw an `InterruptedException`. Thus, if you reached the `catch` block, it must have been after the `process` variable was initialized. If you caught a generic `Exception` (a messy/bad choice!), then "anything" could potentially happen.

Comment: @Rogue, Yeah, now I understand what is interrupted exception better. Thanks, it could be an answer